# Can I declare variable in a more cleaner way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to keep my code clean

```
diagMsg = homu.message['await'].welCH.stat
diagMsg.color = toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33'
diagMsg.msg = diagMsg.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled')
diagMsg.foot = diagMsg.foot.replace('{{prefix}}', homu.guildSettings.get(message.guild.id, 'prefix'))
        console.log(diagMsg)
```

I was wondering if I can do the same thing without declaring diagMsg over and over...
just like this

```
diagMsg = homu.message['await'].welCH.stat
        .color = toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33'
        .msg = diagMsg.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled')
        .foot = diagMsg.foot.replace('{{prefix}}', homu.guildSettings.get(message.guild.id, 'prefix'))
        console.log(diagMsg)
```

Comment: you could consider creating an object `{color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33', ...}` and then merging that with `diagMsg` using `Object.assign()`. But whether that's cleaner is debatable...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate object with all the new properties to assign and then use `Object.assign()`

```
diagMsg = homu.message['await'].welCH.stat
Object.assign(diagMsg, {
   color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33',
   msg: diagMsg.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled'),
   foot: diagMsg.foot.replace('{{prefix}}', homu.guildSettings.get(message.guild.id, 'prefix'))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try object spread:

```
const diagMsg = {
  ...homu.message['await'].welCH.stat,
  color: toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33',
  msg: diagMsg.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled'),
  foot: diagMsg.foot.replace(
    '{{prefix}}', 
    homu.guildSettings.get(message.guild.id, 'prefix')
  )
};
```

Comment: I find this easier to use than `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 0):

Why not put some declarations outside the object literal?

```js
const initalMessage = homu.message['await'].welCH.stat;
const color = toggle === true ? '#ffffff':'#2c2f33';
const msg = initalMessage.msg.replace('{{stat}}', 'Disabled');
const foot = initalMessage.foot.replace('{{prefix}}', homu.guildSettings.get(message.guild.id, 'prefix'));

const diagMsg = {
  ...initalMessage, 
  color,
  msg,
  foot
};
```

Comment: to be honest, that's kinda long... I'm trying to minimize lines. but thanks for the answer 